# How to fetch JSON array without any key in Retrofit (Android)?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I have a `JSON array` without any object(key) inside which there are `JSON Objects` like this :

```
[
  {
    "Type": "Meeting",
    "Name": "TestMeeting",
    "StartDate": "2016-03-22T08:00:00",
    "EndDate": "2016-03-24T09:00:00"
  }
]
```

I tried to parse it but can't find success,Can anyone suggest me how to parse this type of Response using `Retrofit`?

Comment: `List<Event>`, where `Event` has fields for type, name, start date, and end date.

Comment: Why downvoted without any reason, i don't know what i have asked wrong

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for replying your suggestion works :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You Can define a `Class` representing the JSON Object

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Meeting{

@SerializedName("Type")
@Expose
private String type;
@SerializedName("Name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("StartDate")
@Expose
private String startDate;
@SerializedName("EndDate")
@Expose
private String endDate;

public String getType() {
return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
this.type = type;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getStartDate() {
return startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
this.startDate = startDate;
}

public String getEndDate() {
return endDate;
}

public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
this.endDate = endDate;
}

}
```

after that you define Callback for retrofit like that
`Call<List<Meeting>> getMeetings();`

Comment: 10+ for direct requesting list Call<List<Meeting>> getMeetings();

Comment: what if its not an array?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Gson parsing then simple do it like this

```
 var model = Gson().fromJson(response.body()!!.string(), Array<Meeting>::class.java).toList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Json Response :

```
{"contacts":{"918888302649":0,"917207251056":0,"918888804581":0}}
```

POJO Class :

```
public class ContactSyncResponseModel {

    @SerializedName("contacts")
    @Expose
    private Map<String, String> result;

    public Map<String, String> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(Map<String, String> result) {
        this.result = result;
    } }
```